# Stored Procedure MySql giving different result than normal query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is strange. One parameter isn't working correctly when passed as a selection criteria into a stored procedure. It is the section id  which is '1228 BK01'.

Stored Procedure

    `SELECT count(class_id) INTO v_id 
     from courses_semester 
     where course_id = course_id 
     and univ_id = univ_id 
     and dept_id = dept_id 
     and section_id = section_id 
     and semester =semester 
     and year = _year;`

```
SET @p0 = 'BE 871X';
SET @p1 = '1';
SET @p2 = '3';
SET @p3 = '1228 BK01';
SET @p4 = 'fall';
SET @p5 = '2014';
SELECT @p6 AS `v_id` ;
```

Working query

    `SELECT count(class_id) INTO v_id 
     from courses_semester 
     where course_id = course_id 
     and univ_id = univ_id 
     and dept_id = dept_id 
     and section_id = '1228 BK01' 
     and semester =semester 
     and year = _year;`

When '1228 BK01' is passed as a parameter to the sp the result is a count of all the records in the table, which is the wrong behavior. What am I doing wrong here?

Aside: When I just output the parameter it is correctly being passed.

Comment: Are you sure its using the same table? I always use `SELECT * FROM  database.tablename` to be certain its not using from a test or acceptance database etc.

Comment: I tried that too. No difference. Also, isn't procedures only for a particular database?

Comment: You don't show how the SP is returning the count.

Comment: Well, I have an out parameter called v_id and the query is SELECT INTO so I select the out parameter with SELECT @p6 AS `v_id` ; as shown above